# How can I update DateTime in a table row based off of many other tables with a matching key in certain rows SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to be able to update a time value in a row in one table based off of many other tables. This time will only change if one of the other tables rows that has the same key as the row in the main table changes.

I am using Entity Framework with C#

I'm not sure if this can be done with Change Tracking, Triggers, RowVersion, audit tables or something else.

Basically I only want the time to change in one table if the other tables rows have actually been update or a new row has been added.

I was considering checking if the row version changed in a table then I would get the time that the event occurred and then update the other table. Someone said that RowVersion will eventually loop around back to the start so I wasn't sure if that would be an issue. Basically i'm just trying to figure out whats the best way to get the latest update time into one table from all the other tables. It seems like there are many different ways to go about this. Is it possible to do this all in sql using entity framework or should I manage the time value in c# on top of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your object relationships allow it, it would be best to manage this in the objects. You can potentially do this in the database via triggers, but EF would have no clue that updating object A changes LastUpdatedTime in object B. As a result you may read incorrect LastUpdatedTime due to cached object B not being updated.